# Unable to resolve dependancy using ivy.xml, module not found error

Tags: xml, selenium, ant, testng, ivy

This is **ivy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.ste" module="mod"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="binaries" description="binary jars"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.8.5" conf="binaries->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.38.0" conf="binaries->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.json" name="json" rev="20080701" conf="binaries->default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-jxpath" name="commons-jxpath" rev="1.3" conf="binaries->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**Gives following error**

```
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]          module not found: org.testng#testng;6.8.5

[ivy:retrieve] :::: ERRORS
[ivy:retrieve]  Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/te
stng/testng/6.8.5/testng-6.8.5.pom (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.sec
urity.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.prov
ider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification pa
th to requested target)

BUILD FAILED
D:\code\testcases\StudioVoxAnt\build.xml:13: impossible to resolve dependencies:
```

Please let me now where i am doing wrong
Thanks in advance

I am having lib folder already created and build.xml file and ivy.

Comment: built.xml contains        <target name="resolve" description="Retrieve dependencies with ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" conf="binaries"/>
        <!-- <ivy:retrieve conf="binaries" pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" /> -->
    </target>

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263985/ivy-retrieve-leads-to-module-not-found-org-slf4jslf4j-apislf4j-version

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your issue. What version of Java are you running?

Here's my build file:

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: my java version is "1.7.0-ea"

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that might still have this issue: I spent hours in trying to make it work and my problem was something else. Behind a VPN the timeout might not be long enough and it will cause the Server access error.

Try to update the timeout in `ivy.settings` with

`<timeout-constraint name="timeout1" connectionTimeout="300" readTimeout="1000"/>`

more info here: [official documentation](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/settings/timeout-constraints.html)